# "Thanks for interesting to" vs. "Thanks for your interest to": which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I got an email from a professor which started with:

> Thanks for interesting to work with me...

I was wondering if this is grammatically correct. I thought the correct usage should be:

> Thanks for your interest to work with me...

but I am not sure.

Comment: Neither of these expressions is idiomatic. Ones that would be are *Thanks for taking the interest to work with me*; *Thanks for your interest in working with me*.

Comment: @WS2 I see. Thanks. But is the first one grammatically correct? i.e. is it okay to use "interesting" (with "ing") there?

Comment: No, it isn't. A subject interests you, you don't interest it. I would suggest _Thanks for taking an interest in working with me_.